# Firebase firestore security rules not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

[image]

I have a really simple firestore db that looks like the image above.

I want to write a security rule so that only authenticated users can get in, but whatever I write, I always get permission denied.

I have tried:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /users/{user} {
   allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user
   match / {docs = **} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user
   }
 }
}
```

I also tried:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /users/{user} {
   allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user
   match / {docs = **} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user
   }
 }
}
```

I also tried:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if isOwner(userId);
    }
  }

  function isOwner(userId) {
    return request.auth.uid == userId;
  }
}
```

This does not work:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /sessions/{sessionID} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Neither does this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /sessions/{sessionsID} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't see the word `sessions` throughout the post. Or maybe you posted any other screenshot?

Comment: I haven't used the word sessions in the rules at all - but I thought I was selecting all documents however they were nested in folders?

Comment: Not sure, all my rules in firestore start with DB name

Comment: Can you give me an example that works for you? All I need is to allow read, write for authenticated users

Comment: Are those User UID in side sessions doc?

Comment: no the user is just defined on the authentication tab in firestore

Comment: I'm asking what is that ID in sessions collection then? THe value of doc I mean?

Comment: The ID of a session is just that uuid at the top right - it's the name of the doc?

Comment: Can you check my answer if it works?

Comment: Will do - just waiting for changes to take effect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213480/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-davtho1983).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to compare my rules with your database structure.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /sessions/{sessionID=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
}
```

Now this should allow only registered users to gain access.

Comment: I don't see how this rule matches any documents at all. There is no wildcard.

Comment: @DougStevenson performed a rollback. There was a slight confusion during chat.